# $30°$ shift in a star position wrt earth over a month

Tags: coordinate-systems, astronomy

I was looking through the book "Astronomy - Principles and Practice 4th ed. - A. Roy, D. Clarke" and I got stuck at the following lines:

> The month is the next period of any significance to our watcher. During this time, the ideas about the heavens and their movements change. It will be noted that after a few nights the first group of stars seen above the eastern horizon just after sunset is markedly higher at first sight, with other groups under it becoming the first stars to appear. Indeed, after a month, the first group is about thirty degrees above the eastern horizon when the first stars are seen after sunset.

I just got reading, so I don't know anything about Astronomy. I tried to install Stellarium to check it out myself.

My initial thought was, maybe this apparant movement of $30°$ was due to earth's revolution. But it was absurd when I found the following details for a star named "$β$ Ara"

On $1/9/2022$:- Azimuthal coordinates $+193°45' , +11°28'$

[image]

On $1/10/2022$:- Azimuthal coordinates $+207°11' , +1°51'$

[image]

So where is the $30°$ shift? Please help, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Earth orbits the Sun once per year. That means at any given time, the sky appears to revolve at a rate of 360 degrees per year, or 30 degrees per month.

If you were on the equator, where stars at the eastern horizon would appear to rise straight upwards and the sunset occurs at *roughly* the same time of day from month to month, then that means that if you add a month then the star appears to be higher in the sky by 30 degrees at sunset.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered and clarified, yet if you wish, here's the data

Location- $+0°00'00'' ; +0°00'00''$ 
Star - $α$Equ 
On $1/3/2024$ , Alt - $+6°34'$[image]
On $1/4/2024$ , Alt - $+37°20'$[image]

A gap of almost $30°$!